# Java specific regex

Tags: java, regex

I want to write some code that checks whether the input from user matches a specific format. The format is 's' followed by a space and a number, if the input was "s 1 2 3 4", it would call some function. "s 1 2" would also be acceptable. So far I found that this regex works for a specified amount of times:

```
if (inputLine.matches("s \\d+ \\d+")) { }
```

works for 2 numbers after the s, but I need to be able to accept any number of numbers after the s.
Any idea on a regex that would suit my needs? Thank you

Comment: Try this. "s( \\d+)+" There is a space after the opening bracket

Answer (score 4):

Change your regex to

```
if (inputLine.matches("s(?: \\d+)+")) { }
```

to match `s`, space and 1+ sequences of a space followed with 1+ digits.

If you allow 0 numbers after `s`, replace the last `+` quantifier with `*` to match zero or more occurrences.

Since the repeated capturing groups overwrite the group contents, it makes no sense using a capturing group here, thus, I suggest using a *non-capturing* one, `(?:...)`.

Comment: Man, you are always so fast with these regex questions!

Comment: @RafiduzzamanSonnet: I learnt that from [@AvinashRaj](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3297613/avinash-raj).

Comment: Most of the answer I see from you has "(?:" of some sort. I thought "?" means "zero" or "one". Can you point me to a good resource on this? :)

Comment: @RafiduzzamanSonnet: Perhaps, [What is a non-capturing group? What does a question mark followed by a colon (?:) mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-a-question-mark-followed-by-a-colon) can throw some light on it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link!